# Por qual motivo meu código não faz aparecer nada na página?

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu estava tentando fazer uma página de html utilizando o javascript, porém nada acontece, coloquei o script dentro do body, linkei o bootstrap e tudo. Todavia, não funciona, alguém me ajuda por favor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body class="d-block justify-content-center m-0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const title = document.createElement("h1");
        title.innerHTML = "My title";
        const divcominput = document.createElement("div");
        divcominput.classList.add('container');
        divcominput.classList.add('justify-content-center');
        divcominput.classList.add('d-block');
        divcominput.classList.add('bg-dark');

        const inputdadiv = document.createElement("input");
        inputdadiv.type = Text;
        inputdadiv.placeholder = 'Nome completo';

        divcominput.append(inputdadiv);
        divcominput.append(title);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Erro de sintaxe nas linhas `const title = document.createElement(h1)`, `const divcominput = document.createElement(div);` e `const inputdadiv = document.createElement(input);` .Coloque os parâmetros entre aspas: `const title = document.createElement("h1")`, `const divcominput = document.createElement("div");` e `const inputdadiv = document.createElement("input");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem alguns erros de codificação, um exemplo claro de erro:

```
document.createElement(h1);
```

ou seja, pra criar o elemento é entre aspas (ou `h1` é uma variável no código do tipo texto contendo `const h1 = 'h1';` como conteúdo), exemplo correto:

```
document.createElement('h1');
```

Outro fator foi codificado os elementos mas, não adicionou dentro de `BODY` ou algum elemento especifico, ou seja, faltou indicar aonde seria adicionado esse elementos [html](/questions/tagged/html), montei um exemplo mínimo:

```js
const title = document.createElement('h1')
title.innerHTML = "My title";
const divcominput = document.createElement('div');
divcominput.classList.add('container')
divcominput.classList.add('justify-content-center');
divcominput.classList.add('d-block');
//divcominput.classList.add('bg-dark');

const inputdadiv = document.createElement('input');
inputdadiv.type = Text;
inputdadiv.classList.add('form-control');
inputdadiv.placeholder = 'Nome completo';

divcominput.append(inputdadiv);
divcominput.append(title);

//Adicionando
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
x.append(divcominput);
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :)